# What is this char? 65279 ''

Tags: c#, char

I have two strings.

one is "\""

and the other is "\""

I think that they are same.

However, `String.Compare` says they are different.

This is very strange.

Here's my code:

```
string b = "\"";
string c = "\"";

if (string.Compare(b, c) == 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Good");
}

if (c.StartsWith("\""))
{
    Console.WriteLine("C");
}

if (b.StartsWith("\""))
{
    Console.WriteLine("B");
}
```

I expected that it may print "GoodCB".

However, it only prints "B".

In my debugger, `c[0]` is 65279 '' and `c[1]` is 34 '"'. and `b[0]` is '"'.

But I don't know what 65279 '' is.

Is it an empty character?

Comment: What does your string come from? You're probably reading it wrong.

Comment: It very commonly appears as the first character in a utf-16 encoded text file.  Use StreamReader, not FileStream.

Comment: This is very likely related to this excellent answer/explanation here (TL;DR use `StreamReader` if the `string` was loaded from a `Stream`, use `Encoding.GetString()` if it was loaded from `Encoding.GetBytes()`; do not mix the two): https://stackoverflow.com/a/11701560/7293142

Answer (score 100):

It's a [zero-width no-break space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/feff/index.htm).
It's more commonly used as a [byte-order mark (BOM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_Order_Mark).

Comment: How can I remove that char when I cannot sure whether it starts with '' or not?

Comment: Thank you so much! I was hitting the wall till I found your solution!

Comment: Great response, which lead me to continue looking and find this this excellent answer/explanation here (TL;DR use `StreamReader` if the `string` was loaded from a `Stream`, use `Encoding.GetString()` if it was loaded from `Encoding.GetBytes()`; do not mix the two): https://stackoverflow.com/a/11701560/7293142

Answer (score 9):

If you are using Notepad++, try converting to UTF-8 (no BOM), and also make sure ALL your files in the project are the same file system format.

Answer (score 5):

You can remove it with:

```
Trim(new char[]{'\uFEFF','\u200B'});
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are reading from a file you have opened in notepad, it may have added it as it is one of several programs notorious for doing so.

Comment: How can I remove that char when I cannot sure whether it starts with '' or not.

Comment: Notepad and other programs are saving UTF8 files, which is a valid and common format.  The BOM only bothers you when you read the file with the wrong encoding.

Comment: I want to determine whether '' is exist or not using c[0] == '' but I cannot build this.

Answer (score -1):

It is byte order mark(BOM). A BOM is a special marker at the beginning of a file that indicates the byte order of the text data in the file.

We can remove the BOM in JavaScript using the following code

```
    function removeBOM(jsonString) {
        if (jsonString.charCodeAt(0) === 0xfeff) {
            jsonString = jsonString.slice(1);
        } 
        return jsonString;
    }
```