# Encode a string to UTF-8 with BOM in C#

Tags: c#

When I generate a csv file from a string.
I use the following code to encode a string to UTF-8:

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("√");
boolText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

But when I open a file is generated (by notepad++). It has "Encode in UTF-8 without BOM".

I need the file will be generated has UTF-8 so the symbol "√" will be show in excel.

Comment: No, encoding it as UTF-8 would take a string and result in bytes. You're going the opposite direction, but in a weird way which is very likely to lose data. If you want a string with that character in, just use `string text = "√";`. It's very unclear what you're doing with the data afterwards... or where the BOM comes in, to be honest.

Comment: Have you tried `File.WriteAllText` with 3rd parameter encoding=utf8?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11701341/encoding-utf8-getstring-doesnt-take-into-account-the-preamble-bom

Comment: Look at the linked question. You need to create your own `UTF8Encoding`  object to be able to specify if BOM should be added or not.