# unexpected character encountered while parsing value . path '' line 0 position 0

Tags: c#, json, utf-8

I have txt file that contains json formatted data. file content looks like:

[image: Defter.txt]

My conversion code is;

```
byte[] fileContent =  // Read txt file

JournalFake journalFake = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JournalFake>(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(fileContent), new LineNumberConverter());
```

If I observe value of `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(fileContent)` with Quick Watch, value of `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(fileContent)` is below;

[image: value of Encoding.UTF8.GetString(fileContent)]

When I copy this json data to jsoneditoronline.org to check if json is valid, it gives me an error like below(a dot appears at the head of json file).

[image: json data on jsoneditoronline.org]

If I run `JournalFake journalFake = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JournalFake>(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(fileContent), new LineNumberConverter());` statement,
it throws an error: `unexpected character encountered while parsing value . path '' line 0 position 0`

What goes wrong? Any help?

Comment: I lean toward a byte-order mark, but I didn't think `UTF8Encoding.GetString` returned one...

Comment: There must be a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) in the `byte[] fileContent` file.  `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(fileContent)` will not add a BOM but it will not strip it either if present in the file.  Instead, use a `StreamReader` to read the file, it will process it correctly.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317700/strip-byte-order-mark-from-string-in-c-sharp

Comment: Probable duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11701341/encoding-utf8-getstring-doesnt-take-into-account-the-preamble-bom

Comment: use BodyStream property of your Message instead of Body if you are using MSMQ.