# Pass Json string in AFNetworking 2.0

Tags: ios, ios7, afnetworking-2

i want to pass json string in AFNetworking i am using the code below to parse the data to the server.

**My JSON String :**

```
{"Queries":[{"Field":"text_all","Value":"Class1","IsPhrase":false,"Near":0}],"Filter":[{"Key":"Test","Value":["Test","Test2"]}],"Paging":0,"Count":10}
```

**Code:**

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
 manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
      manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
        [manager POST:@“http://www.test.com” parameters:main_dict success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
         {

            NSLog(@"responseString: %@", json);

        }
             failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
         {

         }];
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21487184/posting-json-data-using-afnetworking-2-0

Comment: @danh thanks for your replay but i am using the same code as given your link but its not work for me.