# AFNetworking 2.0 Send Post Request with array of dictionary Parameters

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, afnetworking-2

I want to try post parameter in the following API but the parameter is not getting passed properly, and the response received gives the message that, data is required. So can anyone please help to sort out this problem.

my url is

> forapp.com/api/getContacts.php?data=[ 
>   {"name":"abc","phone":"1234567890"},{"name":"Kate
>   Bell","phone":"9925992599"}  ]

so how i can pass this type of request to the api

```
   AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    NSDictionary *params = @{@"name": @"hello",
                             @"phone": @"1234567890"};
    NSLog(@"Dict %@",params);
    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];

[manager POST:@"http://forapp.com/api/getContacts.php" parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

}];
```

Comment: usu like this. it very easy to call WS with AFNetworking 2.0
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33767908/volunteermatch-api-objective-c/33886449#33886449

Comment: Check out my answer hope this helps :- http://stackoverflow.com/a/35497323/3515115

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just add

**Step-1**

```
// create the dictionary of {"name":"abc","phone":"1234567890"},{"name":"Kate Bell","phone":"9925992599"} this

NSDictionary *params = @{@"name": @"hello",
                         @"phone": @"1234567890"};
```

**Step-2**

```
//create the one array of this output [ {"name":"abc","phone":"1234567890"},{"name":"Kate Bell","phone":"9925992599"} ]

NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:params,nil];
```

**Step-3**

```
// convert your object to JSOn String
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *createJSON = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:objectsInCart
                                                                                options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                                                                                  error:&error]
                                       encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

**Step-4**

```
//create the another one dictionary for send the data for like data=[ {"name":"abc","phone":"1234567890"},{"name":"Kate Bell","phone":"9925992599"} ]

 NSDictionary *pardsams = @{@"data": createJSON};
```

**Step-5**

```
  // finally start your request
  AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

    NSLog(@"Dict %@",pardsams);
    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];

[manager POST:@"http://forapp.com/api/getContacts.php" parameters:pardsams success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

}];
```

Comment: I dont know you can pass the array to your request, the reason we dont know your request , try once

Comment: not working it's give same response data is required

Comment: @Birendra -- check the updated answer bro, it helps you

Comment: @Birendra -- I explain in step by step, it helps you

Comment: @Anbu.karthik what is objectsInCart?

Answer (score 1):

as per this url

```
forapp.com/api/getContacts.php?data=[ {"name":"abc","phone":"1234567890"},{"name":"Kate Bell","phone":"9925992599"} ]
```

You should implement like this

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    NSDictionary *params = @{@"name": @"hello",
                             @"phone": @"1234567890"};
    NSLog(@"Dict %@",params);
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];

[manager POST:@"http://forapp.com/api/getContacts.php" parameters:@{@"data": @[params]} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

}];
```

Answer (score 1):

Add following:

```
// httpClient is a subclass of AFHTTPRequestOperationManager or AFHTTPSessionManager
httpClient.requestSerializer = AFJSONRequestSerializer;
```

**And also check your post array does not include any other object. It just include array.**