# Creating a json object dynamically

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have to make json request of following type.

```
{
  "documents": [
    {
      "file_size": 48597,
      "file_name": "pisa-en.pdf",
      "file_content": "base64String"
    }
  ]
}
```

Following is the way how im creating the json.

```
NSString *json = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"documents\": [ { \"file_size\": %@, \"file_name\": %@\", \"file_content\": \"%@\" } ]}",_imageSizeArray[0],_imageNameArray[0],_baseArray[0]];
```

but the problem is that, the documents array may even contain more than one json object within it. If thats the case How can i create a jsonobject dynamically and embed it within documents array?

Comment: see this once it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35836886/afnetworking-2-0-send-post-request-with-array-of-dictionary-parameters

Comment: if you have a doubt ask me I will added the answer here

Comment: I tried but it is not working. thank you

Comment: how can I iterate over nsmutablearray of file_size, file_name, file_content and create nsdictionary out of it?

Comment: Also Im facing problem while embedding base64string because it is ignoring the cases that contains "/" and hence json error is being thrown

Comment: Try this it would be helful!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16057281/creating-json-format-in-objective-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to take Array and add document object in that array

than at request time you have to convert your array to json string by following code

```
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:myArray options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```