# How to Design the Overlay Menu Above the Home Page?

Tags: ios, objective-c, http-post, nsurlsession, mkoverlay

How to Design the Overlay Instructions Above The View?

```
I HAD 6 buttons....For Each Button I have To show Overlay For That, Before i click on that Button
```

> Suppose... 1) Click button is there...above the Click Button we need
>   to show overlay for click on that button Like That...

```
**
```

> > [I Need Like This Overlay menu over the all Buttons][1]
> >
> > [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIjRF.jpg

**

Comment: are you try for objective-C, or Swift

Comment: For composing URLs see [`NSURLComponents`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLComponents_class/index.html). For sending requests see [`NSURLSession`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/). For configuring a session see `NSURLSessionConfiguration`. For common tasks and questions about network requests, security, HTTP, etc., ask a _specific_ question. Your question is too broad and not a good fit for SO - and will probably be closed. See also [SO Help](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: can you update your question once

Comment: @roselovely -- you nee to like use `Protocol` for your concept, initially fetch User Details and Bank details -- use any NSobjcet or popover controller class, finally use protocol for transfer the value , after that call your webservice it will work , else initially get value of User Details and pass that value to Bank details page and finally call your webservice , it will work

Comment: @Ajay Singh Thakur ....can u give me solution for this

Comment: @CouchDeveloper....Solution Please

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik....can u give the solution for this link ......http://stackoverflow.com/q/35865691/6011888

Answer (score 0):

**Send Parameter to web service using POST method**

Below is code to POST data to web service using **NSURLConnection**.

```
-(void)postData
{
    NSString *content = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"email=%@&name=%@",textEmail.text,textName.text];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"your web service url"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[content dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    dictJson = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
    NSLog(@"Dict Json :- %@",dictJson);   
}
```

Comment: Can You tell step by step process please

Comment: which method you want to use NSURLSession or NSURLConnection for posting data to web service?

Comment: @Dh1_Bh1......can u give the Solution for This...http://stackoverflow.com/q/35865691/6011888

Answer (score 0):

Use [NSURLSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/) instead. NSURLConnection is deprecated.

```
NSString *stringURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?term=%@", BASE_URL, _inputText.text];
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSURLSessionUploadTask *task = [session uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromData:yourData completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                // Do your stuff here
            }];
```

Comment: Bundle that parameter into a dictionary, then embed it in your request.

Comment: Already answered by Dh1_Bh1. I suggest you to read apple documentation first. And, try to use punctuation mark correctly.

Comment: .....can u give the Solution For this....http://stackoverflow.com/q/35865691/6011888

Answer (score 0):

why not use alamofire---

```
                NSDictionary *parameters = @{
                  @"email":  @"myemail1@mailinator.com",
                  @"password": @"123456789",
                  @"accountnumber": @"LiM6N5gBBmqdlQBJGkqcP0h4OKwGbnzoWFcgTG3Z",
                  @"ifcscode": @"ABC"
                };


                NetworkHandler *networHandler = [NetworkHandler sharedInstance];
    [networHandler composeRequestWithMethod:@"http://example.com/enpoint.json"
                                    paramas: parameters
                               onComplition:^(BOOL success, NSDictionary *response){

                                   if (success) { //handle success response

                                       [self handleLoginResponse:response];
                                   }
                                   else{

                                       ProgressIndicator *pi = [ProgressIndicator sharedInstance];
                                       [pi hideProgressIndicator];
                                   }

                               }];
```

you can use postman to check your api

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21487184/posting-json-data-using-afnetworking-2-0 @roselovely see this

Comment: ....can u give The Solution For This...http://stackoverflow.com/q/35865691/6011888

Answer (score 0):

Pass this two variables of FirstViewController to SecondViewController and then try to put below code in place of your code.

Below is code to POST data using **NSURLSession**.

I hope this works for you.

```
-(void)postData
{
    NSString *content = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Name=%@&Email=%@&A/CName=%@&A/CNumber=%@&IFSCCode=%@&TypeOfAccount=%@",name,email,acName,acNumber,ifscCode,typeOfAccount];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"your web service url"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[content dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    [[session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:londonWeatherUrl]
            completionHandler:^(NSData *data,
                          NSURLResponse *response,
                          NSError *error) {

            NSMutableDictionary *dictJson = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
            NSLog(@"Dict Json :- %@",dictJson);   

    }] resume];
}
```

Comment: i want to store three UiviewController's data(1st ViewController Mobile Number , 2nd view controller's name and email and 3rd view controller's bankdetails...) Locally and Hit the API By Sending the All Parameters At A time and  clicking on 3rd view controller's register  button...b...How can i solve this...

Comment: Try to store all parameters in AppDelegate class and then try to retrieve  them in ThirdViewController on click event of any button at time of data Posting.

Comment: How To Store All Parameters in app delegate class...can u please explain step by step

Comment: `YourAppDelegate *appDelegate = (YourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];`
`appDelegate.email = tfEmail.text;`

Comment: Please give me some time so i can code and mail it to you.

Comment: Sorry but i have no idea about this.