# How to Store User Entered Details and Get It Back in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, uitextfield, nsuserdefaults

**How to `Store` user entered details and `Get it Back`  in ios?**

- I had Following **`TextFields`** :
- `UserName`,`Email`, `Re-enter Email id`, `Phone`,
  `State`,`Address`,`Locality`and `Pincode`.
- I want to **`store`** this Details in **`Current viewController`** locally and
  **`display`** this details in **`Next ViewController`**....
- **`How many Ways`** I can **`Store`** and **`Fetch`** the Details, Does anyone know where I can find more information about this?

Comment: What did you try and what didn't work? You mentioned NSUserDefaults, what didn't work when you used that?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you explain it preoperly.

Comment: @gnasher729...how many ways i have to store those details and get those Details Back in ios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to keep user Info persistent(1) or you need this data just to represent it and send to email(2)?
1.If you need to save user info in persistent store using Core Data you have to create entity named 'User' with your attributes (Name, middle name , lastname, username,email, re-enter email id, phone, state, address,locality and pincode) - all this fields can be A String type. Than by the help of 'Editor' tab you should create NSManagedObject subclass for your entity. Than in your VC with textFields you need to fill these data for properties of User instance and save it. And than you can retrieve where you want and display for user.
2.If you need user info just to display and send to email you can make it simpler by using NSUserDefaults for example:

//to save

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:textFieldName.text forKey:@"name"];
```

//to get data

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"name"];
```

Or if there is a need to keep this info all the time and you need it just for one app launch session - just set ViewControllerWhereYouWantToPresentInfo's public properties by text property value of textFields.

Comment: To work with core data i recommend you to use - Magical Record - really simple API to work with your persistent built on top of Apple Core data  https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord

Comment: @rose lovely ... If there will be any free time today/tomorrow i`ll post sample project to the gitHub and share the link for you

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to create variables and store your data there. Once you are ready to go to the next view controller , you can pass the data to your next view controller in this fashion

```
let nextVC = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NextVCStoryBoardId") as! NextVCViewController 
nextVC.variable1 = variable1 //variable1 is in currentVC
nextVC.variable2 = variable2 //variable2 is in currentVC
```

and so on...

You can then push to nextVC with this code

```
self.navigationController!.pushViewController(nextVC, animated: true)
```

In nextVC , you make an action for button to send the data to mail.

Comment: ...please explain in objective c

Answer (score 0):

If the user data is properly stored in core data, you can retrieve it with either a NSFetchedResultsController (FRC) or a simple NSFetchRequest.  In both cases you would create a NSFetchRequest for your 'user' entity and assign it an NSPredicate. The predicate is defined similar to a SQL query.   The NSFetchRequest will retrieve any managed objects that match the predicate.

You might consider though passing these arguments into the second viewController as either arguments or as public properties, rather than fetching and storing them in CoreData. CoreData is great for persisting data on disk when it needs to be query-able (like and SQL database). It's also useful when the UI needs to be frequently updated to reflect changes in the persisted data. You can use NSFetchedResultsContoller to monitor changes to your data mode and automatically notify the UI layer of those changes.

Example using an NSFetchRequest, its the simplest way to do what you are asking.  It assumes you have an entity called "UserDetails" and it has a property called "user_id" to identify a specific user

```
// A pointer to your main thread context, since you will be using this info to 
// populate data on the UI. I typically use a singleton pattern to access my 
// managed object context 
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [DBController sharedInstance].mainManagedObjectContext;
// Create the fetch request
    NSFetchRequest * fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"UserDetails"];

// Assign the predicate
        fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"user_id = %@",<the_users_id>];

// Execute the fetch request on the main thread managed object context
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSArray *objects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    UserDetail *detail = [object firstObject];
```

Comment: NSFetchRequest * fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"<your_entity>"];
    fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"user_id = %@", <user_id>];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *objects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];