# Create Overlay above UIButton in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uibutton, overlay

How to create an overlay above a UIButton in iOS?

In my projects there are 6 UIButtons.

For each button I need to have an overlay instruction above that UIButton, means both UIButton and overlay should be visible.

Once a user clicks on the overlay above the UIButton, overlay will remove/hidden and UIButton should be visible.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/jghint see  this demo it help you to set overlay

Comment: @Birendra...Check and give the solution for this link....http://stackoverflow.com/q/35765980/6011888

Answer (score 0):

`UIButton` is a subclass of `UIView`. This means, you can just use `addSubview:`.

```
[myButton addSubview:myOverlay];
```

To remove the overlay, add a gesture recognizer to the overlay.

Comment: @dasdom....can u please explain in step by step...where i have to declare and use. ...h and .m like that

Comment: @dasdom.....can u give the solution for this...http://stackoverflow.com/q/35865691/6011888

Comment: @dasdom....check and give the solution for this....http://stackoverflow.com/q/35765980/6011888

Answer (score 0):

I will show you how to create an overlay for one button and remove it.

```
#define TAG 1234    //random number to identify the view overlaying the UIButton
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:button.bounds];
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
view.tag = TAG;
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(btnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button addSubview:view];
```

> write this outside viewDidLoad method in .m file of your view
>   controller

```
- (IBAction)btnClicked:(id)sender
{
   //removing overlay on button click
   UIView *view = [sender viewWithTag:TAG];
   [view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: If this answer solves your issue accept the answer and close the thread @roselovely

Comment: ....are u checked that link....how can i do that...http://stackoverflow.com/q/35865691/6011888