# How to send NSDate in JSON Format through AFNetworking in iOS?

Tags: ios, json, nsdate, afnetworking

How to send `NSDate` in JSON Format through AFNetworking in iOS ? Json request -

```
{
    "from_date" : "11/11/2014",
    "to_date" : "11/11/2017"
}
```

**Code -**

```
// Formats the date chosen with the date picker.
- (NSString *)formatDate:(NSDate *)date
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd'/'MM'/'yyyy"];
    NSString *formattedDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    return formattedDate;
}
    - (void)updateToDateField:(id)sender
    {
        UIDatePicker *picker = (UIDatePicker*)toDateField.inputView;
        toDateField.text = [self formatDate:picker.date];
    }
    // Storing the to date in NSString
        dashboard.toDateString = toDateField.text;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21487184/posting-json-data-using-afnetworking-2-0

Comment: can you show something what the output you expect

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik - I want to send JSON request containing date, I am getting proper response in Postman but when I run my code, afnetworking is giving error - status 500.

Comment: ok no problem can you show code

Comment: @NDoc - I think, my date formatter same as yours, and also I am creating the dictionary.

Comment: You have added single quote inside your formate, remove that, like my answer.

Comment: @NDoc - Tried that, did not work.

Comment: @Mr.UB - Yes. I had to convert it into the format that was acceptable by .net server, /Date*****/ format.

Comment: Kindly update your question with your solution or answer your own question, so that it can be helpful for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your `NSDate` in to `String` and send it, just like you send other parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
   [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
   NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

now use `dateString` in you json

Answer (score 0):

I think you are forgot to serialize your request while calling API using AFNetworking Manage class.

Try to add below line in your code.

```
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager;
     manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
     manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
[manager POST:strRequestUrl parameters:dictParams success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
        {

            NSString *msg;
            NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:responseObject
                                                               options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                                                                 error:nil];
            NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
        {

            NSLog(@"request : %@",operation.request);
            NSLog(@"Error is %@",error);

        }];
```

Comment: I have added this. I think, there would be some format to send date string so that the .net server web api would accept it.