# Why is File.ReadAllBytes result different than when using File.ReadAllText?

Tags: c#, string, byte

I have a text file (UTF-8 encoding) with contents "test". I try to get the byte array from this file and convert to string, but it contains one strange character. I use the following code:

```
var path = @"C:\Users\Tester\Desktop\test\test.txt"; // UTF-8

var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
var contents1 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);

var contents2 = File.ReadAllText(path);

Console.WriteLine(contents1); // result is "?test"
Console.WriteLine(contents2); // result is "test"
```

`conents1` is different than `contents2` - why?

Answer (score 6):

As explained in [`ReadAllText`'s documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> This method attempts to automatically detect the encoding of a file based on the presence of byte order marks. Encoding formats UTF-8 and UTF-32 (both big-endian and little-endian) can be detected.

So the file contains BOM ([Byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)), and `ReadAllText` method correctly interprets it, while the first method just reads plain bytes, without interpreting them at all.

[`Encoding.GetString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/744y86tc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says that it only:

> decodes **all the bytes** in the specified byte array into a string

(emphasis mine). Which is of course not entirely conclusive, but your example shows that this is to be taken literally.

Comment: All the documentation rubbish... It will not only detect UTF-8 and UTF-32 [but also  UTF-16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70445598/why-does-file-readalltext-also-recognize-utf-16-encodings)

Answer (score 5):

You are probably seeing the Unicode BOM (byte order mark) at the beginning of the file.  `File.ReadAllText` knows how to strip this off, but `Encoding.UTF8` does not.

Comment: If you check first character `(int)contents1[0]` you will see that this char is the BOM character. More info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784799/what-is-this-char-65279

Answer (score 1):

It's the UTF8 encoding prefix string. It marks the file as UTF8 encoded. `ReadAllText` doesn't return it because it's a parsing instruction.