# Why does File.ReadAllText() also recognize UTF-16 encodings?

Tags: c#, .net, file

I read a file using

```
File.ReadAllText(..., Encoding.ASCII);
```

According [the documentation [MSDN]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_File_ReadAllText_System_String_System_Text_Encoding_) <sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>,

> This method attempts to automatically detect the encoding of a file based on the presence of byte order marks. Encoding formats **UTF-8 and UTF-32** (both big-endian and little-endian) can be detected.

However, in my case the ASCII file incorrectly started with `0xFE 0xFF` and it detected UTF-16 (probably big endian, but I did not check).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [`File` [referencesource]](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/io/file.cs#L827) it uses a StreamReader:

```
private static String InternalReadAllText(String path, Encoding encoding, bool checkHost)
{
  ...
  using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path, encoding, true, StreamReader.DefaultBufferSize, checkHost))
    return sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

and [that StreamReader overload with 5 parameter [MSDN]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_StreamReader__ctor_System_IO_Stream_System_Text_Encoding_System_Boolean_System_Int32_System_Boolean_) is documented to support UTF-16 as well

> It automatically recognizes UTF-8, **little-endian Unicode, big-endian Unicode**, little-endian UTF-32, and big-endian UTF-32 text if the file starts with the appropriate byte order marks. Otherwise, the user-provided encoding is used.

<sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

Since `File.ReadAlltext()` is supposed to and documented to detect Unicode BOMs, it's probably a good idea that it detects UTF-16 as well. However, the documentation is wrong and should be updated. I filed [issue #7515](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-api-docs/issues/7515).