# Can't concatenate string with outputted error

Tags: php

I'm making some form validation and this is how I output it:

```
if(isset($myvalidation)) {
echo $myvalidation->form_errors('pass');
}
```

And it works.

The problem arise when I try to concatenate it with string, like so:

```
if(isset($myvalidation)) {
echo "First" . $myvalidation->form_errors('pass') . "Last";
}
```

The output is odd: I see "First" at the end of my outputted error.

Did I made some mistake or something?

Comment: Do you echo inside `$myvalidation->form_errors('pass')` ?

Comment: where are you doing this concatenation in view?

Comment: What do you mean Dormilich? I store errors in array and then output them by key-value

Comment: @Dormilich pointed it well, would you show us form_errors() ?

Comment: Yes, Haider Ali. In the view, next to the form fields

Comment: _“Did I made some mistake or something?”_ - yes, you are writing functions that echo output directly. Don’t do that, use `return` inside the function to have it _return_ the error message, instead of outputting it directly.

Comment: I use class, and inside of it public function with the logic like this: if(condition) {switch cases... in each, I have if(condition){$this->myerrors(array($item=>"$item should be at least $myvalues characters's."));} just for example

Comment: CBroe, I am not. I use public function with return value of my errors. But it's not the problem, really... I can get the errors. I just don't get it why I can't concatenate them with string

Comment: do you use var_dump? don't.

Comment: @zohigekid The observed behaviour can be easily explained, if `->form_errors()` contains echo statements.

Comment: @Dormilich you're right! :) I did echo for some reason in that function... I switched it for return, and it worked. But I noticed some odd character at the end of the output: "&#65279;" I didn't copy anything and I am writing in UTF-8... Do you have any idea where is this coming from?

Comment: @zohigekid That could be the HTML-encoded BOM. cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784799/what-is-this-char-65279

Comment: Thousand of thanks to you, @Dormilich!

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing it in blade do it like this

```
@if(isset($myvalidation)) 
    <p>First {{$myvalidation->form_errors('pass')}} Last</p>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error may be that form_errors() does not return a `string` value.

Depending on the framework you're using, try one of the following:

```
if(isset($myvalidation)) {
  echo "First" . (string) $myvalidation->form_errors('pass') . "Last";
}
```

or

```
if(isset($myvalidation)) {
  echo "First" . $myvalidation->form_errors('pass')->__toString() . "Last";
}
```