# &#65279; appearing in textarea elements but not in string

Tags: javascript, html, dom, textarea, special-characters

I am working on an autocomplete used inside a textarea. I know there is some autocompletes already created, but anyway.

It works well, but if when I'm typing something and I select one or many characters and delete it, a `&#65279;` appears at the end of my string (or where I was inside it). I tried to replace it while retrieving my html with replaceAll, but it doesn't work (There is not this special char when I use an indexOf). The problem is he doesn't find any result because of this char. Let's see an exemple :

This is my array (a little bit cut but we don't really care)

```
let array = [{
    name: "test",
    value: "I'm a test value"
},
{
    name: "valueorange",
    value: "I'm just an orange"
},

// This is how I get the contents of my span (I tried both innerHTML and innerText, same results). 
// Same while using .text() or .html() with jquery

let value = jqElement.find("#searching-span")[0].innerHTML.substring(1).toLowerCase();
    
value = value.replaceAll("&nbsp;", " ");
value = value.replaceAll("&#65279;", "");
```

I can replace every `&nbsp;` without any problems. Finally I check with a loop if there is some value with indexOf on each value, and if it returns anything I push it and get it in a new array. But when I have `&#65279;` I have no results.

Any idea how I can resolve it ?

I tried to be clear, I hope my english wasn't so bad, sorry if I made many mistakes !

Comment: Look here for possible answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784799/what-is-this-char-65279

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Character entities and HTML escaped characters like `&nbsp;` and `&#65279;` appearing in HTML **source code** are converted by the HTML **parser** into unicode characters like `\u00a0` and `\ufeff` **before** being inserted into the DOM.

If replacing them in JavaScript, use their unicode characters, not HTML escape sequences, to match them in DOM strings. For example:

```js
p.textContent = p.textContent.replaceAll("\ufeff", '*'); // zwj
p.textContent = p.textContent.replaceAll("\xa0", '-');   // nbsp
```

```html
<p id="p">&#65279;&nbsp;&#65279;&nbsp;&#65279;&nbsp;</p>
```

Note that zero width joiners are uses a lot in emoji character sequences and arbitrarily removing *may* break emoji character decoding (although decoding badly formed emoji strings is almost a prerequisite for handling emojis in the wild).

Second note: I am not suggesting this as a means of circumventing badly decoding characters that have been encoded using a Unicode Transform Format. Making sure decoding is performed correctly is always a better option.

Comment: Incredible answer, it works perfectly for me ! Thanks you very much ! Was searching a solution since yesterday and you saved me !