# char to int comparison behaves differently in code and debugger / Watch Window in VS

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have string like that:

[image]

Now I have loop that removes 1st character if this first character's numeric value `65279`

```
while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(json) && json[0] == 65279)
{
    json = json.Substring(1, json.Length - 1);
}

return json;
```

I have break point at first `{` so before `Substring` is executed

and now in watch window I type `json[0] == 65279` and it returns `FALSE` despite that it must have returned `TRUE` in order to enter that loop!

[image]

what's going on here?

BTW: I'm aware that the same goal can be achieved with

`.TrimStart(new char[] { Convert.ToChar(65279) });`

instead of loop

Repro code:

```
var json = $"{Convert.ToChar(65279)}{Convert.ToChar(65279)}{{";
Console.WriteLine(json[0] == 65279);
```

Comment: ascii 65279 ?   an ascii is always< 255

Comment: @Frenchy fixed that `ASCII` => `character's numeric value`

Comment: @Selvin `var myString = Convert.ToChar(65279).ToString();`
`var myChar = Convert.ToChar(65279);`
`Console.WriteLine(myString.Length);`
`Console.WriteLine(myChar);`
`Console.WriteLine((int)myChar);` try that

Comment: json is unicode, so you have to serialize it

Comment: I want to deserialize it, but `Newtonsoft.Json` FAILs to parse that because of those two characters at the beginning

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784799/what-is-this-char-65279

Comment: Please share a [mcve]. Screenshots aren't helpful.

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1306238/incorrect-surrogate-char-comparison-result-in-watc.html

Comment: The value I suspect you want to test with is `"\uFEFF"`. rather than `"\u65279"` @Selvin.

Comment: This has been borken for quite a while already.  Tools > Options > Debugging > General, tick "Use the legacy C# and VB expression evaluators".  But doesn't fix it for .NETCore/.NET5 projects, hopefully a good reason for them to finally fix the bugs.

Comment: @mjwills added the code to repro

Comment: instead of `Convert.ToChar(65279)` just use `'\uFEFF'`, `'\xFEFF'` or `(char)0xFEFF`, much shorter and more readable. 0xFEFF is famous but no one knows what the magic number 65279 means